# How to add a h1 header with a message using javascript ( The code below is a new year 2023 countdown timer). Point out my error please

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

When the countdown comes to end i want to make h1[1] and h1[2] header visible and hide h1[0] hide.
I did in a way given below in javasript code segment but h1[1] and h1[2] is not getting visible. Please someone point out my error and how to fix it?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.body.querySelector("h1").textContent = "HAPPY NEW YEAR";
document.body.getElementsByTagName("h1")[1].style.display = inline; //Not working
document.body.getElementsByTagName("h1")[2].style.display = inline; //Not working
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>New Year Countdown</h1>
    <h1 style="display:none">HAPPY NEW YEAR</h1>
    <br>
    <h1 style="display:none">WELCOME 2023!</h1>
    <div class=" container" id="countdown">
        <div class=" row" id="time">
            <div class="col" id="days">
                <h2>00</h2>
                <h6>DAYS</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="hours">
                <h2>00</h2>
                <h6>HOURS</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="minutes">
                <h2>00</h2>
                <h6>MINUTES</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="seconds">
                <h2>00</h2>
                <h6>SECONDS</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="source.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: **Closing as typo**: `inline` should be a String `"inline"`. Sometimes it just helps to open Developer Tools Console and read out the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an `ID` to your `H1` and use `getElementsById('h1-id')`

and then update `visibility: hidden` css style property.

Comment: Thnx!  i understood

Answer (score 0):

i understand the problem you are facing.
first of try removing in-line css that you are applying in the html file and shift that to the `<style></style>` inside the `<header></header>` section of the html document, **we do this because inline-css is provided more importance** than other form of style you inject in the document.

html

```
<h1 class="headers" id="new_year_cntdwn">New Year Countdown</h1>
<h1 class="headers">HAPPY NEW YEAR</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="headers">WELCOME 2023!</h1>
```

Add the css

```
.headers{
        display: none;
    }
    #new_year_cntdwn{
        display: inline;
    }
```

And for the JavaScript Portion try using this after removing the inline css

Here we iterate through the array (here the header array that is being selected)
if you want more information on `querySelectorAll` or `forEach` methods try reffering to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

```
document.querySelectorAll(".headers").forEach(header=>header.style.display="block")
document.querySelector("#new_year_cntdwn").style.display="none"
```

Comment: it will be better if you create a variable or constant to store the data which are being passed by the `const obj1 = document.querySelectorAll(".headers")` so that you have to only call obj and do what you want.

Comment: Thnx a lot. You explained very well about this approach.